# Distribute budget proportionally to all the employees with min and max condition using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have got budget which needs to be proportionally allocated to the employees, initially we will try to allocate the budget as per the proposed merit increase%, if the budget is left over, then we will try to adjust the 'final merit hike%', if we allocate the budget as per as shown in 'final merit hike%' column then we can utilize complete budget but another condition we need to consider is, merit hike% should be within 3%-15% range and we should make sure we are not over utilize or under utilize the given budget.
I need your help in fixing the formula for 'Final merit hike%' to fit within 3% to 15% range by making sure we are utilizing the full budget.

Please note that, in the below example proposed hike% for employee name "F" is 0%, it's completely fine as this employee is considered as poor performer, hence we proposed 0% hike in the first place itself. However for the rest of the employees we can make adjustments to the final merit hike% but it should fall within the range 3% to 15% and the budget should not be over utilized or under utilized.

Please look at the following example and let me know, if anything is unclear, looking forward for your help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss1DH.jpg)